# Bootstrap 3: How to align text in button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using following code to create a button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" name="send" id="send" value="Send Password" ">
```

now its text is in center how do i float  **Send Password** to left  of button  as this is set inside button tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has it's own [text alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment), however since you're using button classes on this input, the text-alignment will be overridden. You can however, just create your own rule which is more specific than Bootstrap's rules:

```
#send {
  text-align:left;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/HBsJKc7gVh)**